# More than one arguments passing for event listener

Tags: javascript

If we have a function `foo`, and `bar` is a random variable, what would be the difference between invoking it as `this.foo` and `foo(bar)`?

How could we invoke the function after an event with two parameters?

For example:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("id1");
div1.addEventListener('onEvent', this.foo);
```

I tried to do the following:

```
var bar = "382";
div1.addEventListener('onEvent', function(event) { baz(event, bar) } );
```

but it was not successful. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Why wasn't it successful, it seems just fine? Maybe you're asking about scope, and the value of `this` inside event handlers.

Comment: doing `('onEvent', this.foo)` only the event argument will be passed to the callback, unless `this.foo` is some result of `bind()` where you can bind other arguments to be added to the argument list when invoked

Comment: Pass an object as argument, then you'll have as many vars as you want ;)